# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in wpf combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Simple question, but I'm stuck a few hours so maybe you can save me couple of hours.

I have a combobox, and I want to show the user selection on MessageBox

My xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="product_combobox" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Mail version" Height="24" Margin="155,105,155,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="210" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="False" Content="--Product--"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

code behind:

```
        private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender , SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)(this.product_combobox.SelectedValue);               
            string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
```

When I run in debug I see the exeption:

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`

, please help me to save more hours.

---

EDIT:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender , SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(product_combobox.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
```

also gives same exeption

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside `comboBox_SelectionChanged` and observing the value of `product_combobox.SelectedValue`?  Have you checked the `InnerException` of your `TargetInvocationException`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. While `product_combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()` might not return what you think, it does not throw an exception. You should check the call stack of the exception.

Comment: What version of VS are you using and what is your .Net framework set as?

Comment: @Tronald VS 2015 framework 4.5.2

Comment: @Tronald I changed to framework 4.6.2 and now it works

Comment: Cool, I would still recommend setting the items in the code behind (check out my answer) as you may find that reflection will return the ComboBoxItem object name embedded with the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain .NET Framework versions have an issue with reflection of ComboBox items if the items are set in XAML. Setting the items in the code behind will fix the issue.

```
  product_combobox.Items.Add("--Product--");
  product_combobox.Items.Add("Item1");
  product_combobox.Items.Add("Item2");
  product_combobox.Items.Add("Item3");
```